# Difference between expectation values of $L^2$, $L_z$ and measuring $L^2$, $L_z$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, wavefunction, hydrogen

I was given with this hydrogen radial wavefunction

$$ R_{21} =\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}Y^0_1 + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}Y^1_1\right) $$

and was asked to find

**a)** What are the expectation values of the $L^2$, and $L_z$?

**b)** If you measured the orbital angular momentum squared $L^2$, what values might you get? Do the same for $L_z$.

The problem is I cannot understand the difference between the answer to both **a** & **b**, aren't they referring to the same answer?

My answer for $L^2$ is:
$$ L^2 \psi = l(l+1)h^2 \psi
\\ = 2h^2 \psi$$
hence the expectation value for $L^2$ is $2h^2$, now what should be my answer for **b**)?

Comment: If $R_{21}$ is an eigenfunction of $L_z$ then all measurements of this quantity when the wavefunction is in such a state will yield the same value always. So, in that case, the answers to a) and b) will be the same. I am currently learning QM as well so someone correct me if this is incorrect.  Your wavefunction is conveniently expressed in terms of the eigenstates of both $L^2$ and $L_z$ so by acting with these operators onto the eigenstates gives the possible values immediately.

Comment: same thoughts here, also waiting for the veteran's confirmation.

Comment: your own lecture notes work out this exact problem on page 5, under "class excercise", but correctly distinguish the wavefunction $\psi $, the radial function R and the spherical harmonic Y. http://www.physics.udel.edu/~msafrono/626/Lecture%201.pdf

Comment: $L^2$ should be $l(l+1)\hbar^2$ with a h-bar

Comment: Or rather, $L^2$ has *eigenvalues* $l(l+1)\hbar^2$ I think?

Answer (score 1):

The two questions *are* slightly different. Each individual measurement of $L^2$ or $L_z$ will return an eigenvalue. In this case, you have only one possible measurement for $L^2$ (corresponding to $l=1$), but you have two possible measurements for $L_z$; 2/3 of the time you'll get $m=1$, and 1/3 of the time you'll get $m=0$.

The expectation value, on the other hand, is essentially asking, if you took a whole bunch of measurements and averaged them, what would you get?  For $L^2$, since all of your measurements are the same, you'll again get the eigenvalue when you average them, but for $L_z$ you'll get something in between.